# Unterschied zwischen "bequem", "gemütlich" und "angenehm"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, meaning

Ich weiß, dass die drei Adjektive als *comfortable* übersetzt werden können. Aber was ist denn der Unterschied? Sind sie austauschbar?

Comment: Ich denke das [hier](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/629/1691) könnte dir nützlich sein.

Comment: Vergiss nicht "komfortabel" und "behaglich"? ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Angenehm** beschreibt ein Gefühl – eher etwas, dem Du Dich gerne (und unter Umständen auch längere Zeit) aussetzt bzw. aussetzen würdest.

Wenn etwas **bequem** ist (für gewöhnlich ein Sitz oder eine Liegefläche oder–figurativ–eine bestimmte Aktion), dann ist das daraus resultierende Gefühl in der Regel angenehm.
Beispiele hier:

> Eine bequeme Couch
>   -> es ist angenehm, darauf zu sitzen.
>
> Samstag morgens um 8:00 kann man bequem einkaufen.
>   (Es ist z.B. nicht voll -> weniger Stress als gewöhnlich) -> Umgangssprache

**Gemütlich** beschreibt entweder eine Person ohne Hektik/eine langsame Person oder eine Situation/ein Gesamtbild.

So kann eine Wohnung gemütlich aussehen, man kann morgens gemütlich seinen Kaffee trinken, oder auf den Nachbarn warten, der sich Zeit lässt vorbeizukommen, da er ein eher gemütlicher Typ ist.

Answer (score 10):

Ich zitiere aus Wiktionary und Duden:

**angenehm**: eine positive Empfindung auslösend
**gemütlich**: eine angenehme, behagliche Atmosphäre schaffend
**behaglich**: Gemütlichkeit erweckend
**bequem**: beim Verwenden ein gutes Gefühl gebend
**komfortabel**: mit Annehmlichkeiten, Komfort, guter technischer Ausrüstung

Schlussfolgerung:

- *angenehm* bezieht sich auf das (positive) Gefühl, welches man empfindet
- *gemütlich* und *behaglich* drücken so ziemlich das gleiche aus; sie beziehen sich auf die Atmosphäre/Stimmung, die vermittelt wird
- *bequem* bezieht sich auf die Benutzung von Gegenständen; genauer das (positive) Gefühl, welches diese hervorrufen
- *komfortabel* bezieht sich auf die Ausstattung, sprich Verfügbarkeit auch jener Sachen, die nicht zwingend notwendig sind

Answer (score 2):

Die drei Adjektive liegen in der Bedeutung recht dicht beieinander und dürften sich hauptsächlich durch ihre Kollokationen, also ihre Wortverbindungen, unterscheiden.
Wenn man von Schuhen oder von einem Sessel spricht, würde man nie von gemütlichen Schuhen oder einem gemütlichen Sessel sprechen, sondern bequem gebrauchen.
Ein Raum, ein Zimmer wird als gemütlich empfunden, wenn man sich darin wohl fühlt.
Hier würde man nie ein bequemes Zimmer sagen. Das Adjektiv angenehm hat eine größere Anwendungsbreite. Das Wetter kann angenehm sein, ebenso die Wassertemperatur beim Baden in einem See und viele andere Dinge mehr. Mit Lexikondefinitionen für diese drei Adjektive kommt man nicht sehr weit, die Definitionen sind zu ähnlich, es sei denn, das Lexikon gibt typische Kollokationen wie bequeme Hausschuhe an, und erklärt, nicht zu weit, nicht zu eng, hautsympathisch etc.

Comment: Für mich können Schuhe und Sessel durchaus gemütlich sein. Die Aussage, dass diese Kollokation nie zusammen auftreten ist schlichtweg falsch. Eine simple Google-Abfrage bestätigt dies. Eine Corpus-Suche unterstützt meine Aussage auch. Wenngleich "gemütliche Schuhe" nahezu gegen Null tendiert, der "gemütliche Sessel" ist sehr gängig.

Comment: Ja, es gibt natürlich individuell verschiedenen Gebrauch. Für mich wirkt gemütlich auf die Sinne, aufs Gemüt.